# Solving the wave equation in 3 dimensions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

[image]

I've been set the question above, and I'm having some problems on where to start. I haven't come across PDE's in more that two dimensions before so I'm quite confused.

I started by trying to use d'Alembert's formula for this given v however first of all I thought that d'Alemberts formula only worked in two dimensions furthermore, say we could apply d'Alembert in $\mathbb{R}^3$ then determining u from our definition of it and v(x,t;s) = $\frac{1}{2c}\int^{x+t}_{x-t}$f(y,s)dy seems unfindable. I also tried determining u$_{tt}$ and u$_{xx}$ immediately however I couldn't find a viable way to do so with what I had been told in the question.

I won't be marked on this question however I would still prefer to not be given the answer to it. These equations I've been told will be relevant in my finals hence I would rather someone explain where to start on this question and I will try to complete the rest myself.

Comment: Just compute the derivatives of $u$, using [differentiation under the integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), and then see what $u_{tt} - u_{xx}$ yields in terms of $v$. For example, $$u_{t} = v(x,t;t) + \int_{0}^{t} v_{t}(x,t;s) ds $$

Comment: @MatthewCassell Thank you for your comment, thanks to you I've pretty much completed the problem however I have one small question using differentiation under the integral for u$_t$, as written above do we not get 2v(x,t:t)+$\int^{t}_{0}$v(x,t,s)ds which eventually gives u$_{tt}-u$_{xx}$=2f(x,t) or is the partial derivative wrt t of v(x,t:;t)=0 I'm unsure how I can show that is true?